# Почему не отправляет на две форми в чем ошибка?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы
    $errors = array(); // контейнер для ошибок
    // проверяем корректность полей
    if($_POST['user_name'] == "")    $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваше имя' не заполнено!";
    if($_POST['user_phone'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваш телефон' не заполнено!";



    // если форма без ошибок
    if(empty($errors)){     
        // собираем данные из формы
        $message  = "Имя клиента: " . $_POST['user_name'] . "<br/>";
        $message .= "Телефон клиента: " . $_POST['user_phone'] . "<br/>";

        send_mail($message); // отправим письмо
        // выведем сообщение об успехе
        $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;'>Сообщение успешно отправлено!</span>";
        $err = 0;
    }else{
        // если были ошибки, то выводим их
        $msg_box = "";
        foreach($errors as $one_error){
            $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
        }
        $err = 1;
    }



    // делаем ответ на клиентскую часть в формате JSON
    echo json_encode(array(
        'result' => $msg_box,
        'err' => $err
    ));


    // функция отправки письма
    function send_mail($message){
        // почта, на которую придет письмо
        $mail_to = "...@gmail.com";
        $mail_to = "...@gmail.com";
        // $mail_to = "librus81@gmail.com";
        // тема письма
        $subject = "Заказ звонка Fast Fillment";

        // заголовок письма
        $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Заказ звонка 
             <...@gmail.com>\r\n"; // от кого письмо

             // отправляем письмо 
             mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
         }

     ?>
```

Comment: а сама ошибка то почему не указана

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, ты вызываешь функцию send_main один раз. В этой функции один раз вызывается функция mail.

Так же я не вижу смысла выводить все ошибки через цикл for.

Достаточно сделать: $msg_box = $errors[0];